# Save data persistent in Android WebView

Tags: android

I am using the web view in which I require to enter the userid/password. I want to keep userid/password in the cache so that i don't need to enter the userid/password again. It destroy when i restart the device and close the app.

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Thanks

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want to keep userid/password in the cache so that i don't need to enter the userid/password again. How can i this

Comment: why don't you just use SharedPreferences to store this data?

Comment: How can i use the SharedPreferences in case of web view

Answer (score 1):

With Android WebApps you can call Android code from JavaScript and vice versa. So all you have to do is to bind JavaScript functions and Android code to store username and password and call it from within the JavaScript function.

You can find a reading and an example in the [Android developers guide for web apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Scroll down to 'Binding JavaScript code to Android code'. Well, the rest of the page is also very interesting.

Comment: It store the username/password but when i reboot the device then it lost..why its so..please let me know just check my above code. is it enough to do so

Comment: Websettings live only as long as the Activity or the context they reside in. To store some data for longer you must store them persistents somewhere. No matter if that is a SharedPreference or any other way, your website must communicate to the Android code, because the Android code handles persisting and reading of the data like username and password.

Comment: Can you give an example to achieve it to save the userid and password in case of web view

Comment: Follow the link in my answer and scroll down to 'Binding JavaScript...'. There's an example for the three parts of Android, JavaScript AMD the interface between them. The example shows a Toast.